# Invoke action in p:menuitem

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am trying to invoke an action on a `menuitem` to call a method in a bean, but it never works:

```
<p:submenu label="Par type">
   <p:menuitem value="Idée Simple" action="#{ideeBean.getAllIdeeByType()}"  />
    <p:menuitem value="Idée d’amélioration"  />
    <p:menuitem value="Idée de résolution de problème"  />
 </p:submenu>
```

And this is the method:

```
public String getAllIdeeByType(){
   ideesc= ideeService.getAllIdeeByType("Idée Simple");
   return"/pages/ideepar.xhtml";
}
```

This is all the code:

```
                <center>

                    <h:form>
                        <p:megaMenu orientation="horizontal" style="margin-top:10px">
                            <p:submenu label="Idee" icon="ui-icon-pencil">

                                <p:column>
                                    <p:submenu label="Par type">

                                        <p:menuitem value="Idée Simple"
                                            action="#{ideeBean.getAllIdeeByType}" />
                                        <p:menuitem value="Idée d’amélioration" />
                                        <p:menuitem value="Idée de résolution de problème" />
                                    </p:submenu>
                                </p:column>
                            </p:submenu>
</p:megaMenu>
                    </h:form>
                </center>
```

Comment: what did you mean it never work, can you show us the rest of your code please?

Comment: i mean by it never works that it doesn't redirect to the url "/pages/ideepar.xhtml" and it just adds # to the url .

Comment: try to use just `ideepar.xhtml` instead of the full url `/pages/ideepar.xhtml`

Comment: you are using two forms why? can you remove one?

Comment: i tried it's the same problem

Comment: try to use just one form

Comment: i did it . the problem persist